# Fortran segmentation fault in pointer array

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran

I have a segmentation fault problem in fortran. 
I allocate a pointer array by calling a subroutine and pass this array to another subroutine.

I compile this program by PGI fortran 9.0.2 on Linux machine.
Here is my test program. How should I fix this problem?

Thank you very much for your help.

```
module hogehoge
  implicit none
  type foo
     real, pointer :: x(:)=>null()
  end type foo
contains
  subroutine hogehoge_func(foox)
    type(foo), intent(inout) :: foox
    integer i
    allocate(foox%x(2048))
    do i = 1, 2048
       foox%x(i)=i
    end do
  end subroutine hogehoge_func
end module hogehoge

!main program------------------------------------------
program test
  use hogehoge
  implicit none
  type(foo) :: foox
  call hogehoge_func(foox)

  print*, 'in main program'
  print*, foox%x(1:20)
  call hoge(foox%x)

end program test
subroutine hoge(foox)
  use hogehoge
  implicit none
  type(foo), intent(in) :: foox

  print*, 'in subroutine'
  print*, foox%x(1)

end subroutine hoge
```

Here is the output.

```
 in main program
    1.000000        2.000000        3.000000        4.000000
    5.000000        6.000000        7.000000        8.000000
    9.000000        10.00000        11.00000        12.00000
    13.00000        14.00000        15.00000        16.00000
    17.00000        18.00000        19.00000        20.00000
 in subroutine
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: DaveP has a correct answer below. In addition, if you compiled your program with -C (check bounds), you would get a very informative message about what went wrong with your program.

Answer (score 7):

You need to change the last line of the main program from:

```
call hoge(foox%x)
```

to

```
call hoge(foox)
```

If you had defined the routine `hoge` in a module and imported that, then the compiler would pick up this type error.