# Some questions about a piece of Fortran code, new to Fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran

I ran into some piece of Fortran code rather difficult to understand. 
  1. What is the name of structure of code `/ (i1,i1=0,nn-1) /`?
  How can I print it directly in the code to see its content? 
  2. I'm looking for ways to change value of `nn` without re-compiling, how should I do this? `nn` supposed to be the length of array `omega`. 
  3. How should I setup the length of `omega` in case of changeable `nn`?
I mean when I'll have no `parameter (nn=20)` anymore.

```
  program test_20140919
  ! test
  implicit none
  integer nn
  parameter (nn=20)
  real omega(nn)

  call test_real(nn, 2.0, 4.0, omega)

  print *, omega
  end program test_20140919

  !c ===

  subroutine test_real(nn, o1, o2, omega)      
  integer nn
  real o1, o2
  real omega(nn)

  print *, nn
  omega = o1 +  (o2*o1)*(/ (i1,i1=0,nn-1) /)/real(nn-1)
  print *, real(nn)
  return
  end
```

I've compiled this with line `gfortran test.f -ffree-form -o test` in terminal.

**UPD** 
   Revised version of the code due to answers from Vladimir F:

```
      module subs

        implicit none

      contains

        subroutine test_real(nn, o1, o2, omega)      
          integer nn
          real o1, o2
          real :: omega(:)

          if (.not. allocated(omega)) allocate(omega(nn))
          omega = o1 +  (o2*o1)*(/ (i1,i1=0,nn-1) /)/real(nn-1)
          print *, real(nn)

        end subrotine

      end module

      program test_20140920
      ! test

        use subs

        implicit none

        integer nn
        real, allocatable :: omega(:)

        read(*,*) nn

        allocate(omega(nn))

        call test_real(nn, 2.0, 4.0, omega)

        print *, omega
      end program test_20140920
```

Comment: You can also use command line input redirecting (`>`) to redirect a text file as a standard input. The program will then read from the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) This is `(/ ... /)` is an array constructor.

The expression `(i1,i1=0,nn-1)` is an implied-do loop.

2) Read it using a read statement

```
     integer :: nn

     read(*,*) nn
```

3) Use an allocatable array

```
real, allocatable :: omega(:)

...

allocate(omega(nn))
```

I recommend you to read a Fortran tutorial or a Fortran book and familiarize yourself with these concepts.

Comment: 2) I've expected using of command-line-parameters not simple reading from input.
3) It's ok, but in that case I should add an interface for the subroutione to the code.

Comment: Expected, but didn't specify it. Look for `get_command_argument()` in your compiler's manual. 3) No interface block is necessary or even desirable, learn modules. Inside the subroutine use an assumed shape array `omega(:)`. No need for it to be allocatable in the subroutine.

Comment: Could you explain, why using of modules is more preferred than using of interfaces? My first idea was it's easier to separate main program from auxilary subroutines in several files.

Comment: This is too much for a short comment. Start here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11953087/proper-use-of-modules-in-fortran and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412834/correct-use-of-modules-subroutines-and-functions-in-fortran