# Fortran function that accepts arbitrary sized rank-1 arrays

Tags: matlab, fortran, fortran90, indices

How can I write a function that accepts arrays of arbitrary size, provided they are of rank 1?
This is exactly what the intrinsic function `shape` can do, so I don't think my request is too demanding.
Actually, the function `shape` does more. It can (obviously) accept array of any shape, that is arbitrary rank and arbitrary length along each dimension.

This question is aimed to write a function `sub2ind` which corresponds to the MATLAB function of the same name.

Comment: As part of this question you presumably also care about the function result being an array of some arbitrary (but related) size?

Comment: Well, I'd like to know the most general answer, but a first step would be to answer in the case the function gives a scalar as output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, but functions accepting any array size were possible in Fortran since Fortran functions were invented. (Although some tricks were sometimes involved before FORTRAN 77). Any textbook or tutorial will treat this problem.

Modern style assumed shape:

```
  function f(a)
    real :: a(:)
    do i = 1, size(a)
    ...
  end functions
```

explicit size:

```
  function f(n, a)
    real :: a(n)
    do i = 1, n
    ...
  end functions
```

assumed size:

```
  function f(n, a)
    real :: a(*)
    do i = 1, n
    ...
  end functions
```

For assumed shape, explicit interface (best using modules) is necessary.

Comment: I dont't want to give the size explicitly, so I first and third ways are needed, but I don't know what's the difference; neither I know which way I should use a module.. (I'm new to fortran)

Comment: You must read a textbook then. And search stackoverflow. There are good questions and answers about this. For advanced work with arrays you need modules.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412834/correct-use-of-modules-subroutines-and-functions-in-fortran http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240510/how-do-you-use-fortran-90-module-data http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11953087/proper-use-of-modules-in-fortran